# ¿Porqué Python modifica automáticamente algunos datos en binario leídos desde el puerto serie?

Tags: python-3.7, pyserial

Estoy haciendo una aplicación que debe leer los datos que llegan al puerto serie y graficarlos en tiempo real. La información viene codificada en binario siguiendo una estructura similar a la siguiente:

`b'\x24\x24\x02\xAF\x00\xA7\xF3\x08\x00\x02\x00\xD7\x00\x00\x00\x01\xA1\x00\x00\x00\xAB\xF3\x08\x00\x02\x00\xDB\x00\x00\x00\x01\xA1\x00\x00\x00\xAF\xF3\x08\x00\x02\x00\xD9\x00\x00\x00\x01\xA1\x00\x00\x00\xB3\xF3\x08\x00\x02\x00\xDA\x00\x00\x00\x01\x9E\x00\x00\x00\xB7\xF3\x08\x00\x02\x00\xDE\x00\x00\x00\x01\xA1\x00\x00\x00\xBB\xF3\x08\x00\x02\x00\xD7\x00\x00\x00\x01\xA4\x00\x00\x00\xBF\xF3\x08\x00\x02\x00\xD7\x00\x00\x00\x01\x9D\x00\x00\x00\xC3\xF3\x08\x00\x02\x00\xD7\x00\x00\x00\x01\xA2\x00\x00\x00\xC7\xF3\x08\x00\x02\x00\xDB\x00\x00\x00\x01\x9D\x00\x00\x00\xCB\xF3\x08\x00\x02\x00\xD8\x00\x00\x00\x01\xA3\x00\x00\x00\xCF\xF3\x08\x00\x04\x00\xD7\x00\x00\x00\x01\xA7\x00\x00\x00\x02\xDA\x00\x00\x00\x04\x97\x6D\x01\x00'`

Ese dato necesito almacenarlo en algún lugar para luego manipular la información y realizar los gráficos correspondientes. Pero por ejemplo si lo almaceno en una variable `a` y luego imprimo el valor de esa variable obtengo:

`b'$$\x02\xaf\x00\xa7\xf3\x08\x00\x02\x00\xd7\x00\x00\x00\x01\xa1\x00\x00\x00\xab\xf3\x08\x00\x02\x00\xdb\x00\x00\x00\x01\xa1\x00\x00\x00\xaf\xf3\x08\x00\x02\x00\xd9\x00\x00\x00\x01\xa1\x00\x00\x00\xb3\xf3\x08\x00\x02\x00\xda\x00\x00\x00\x01\x9e\x00\x00\x00\xb7\xf3\x08\x00\x02\x00\xde\x00\x00\x00\x01\xa1\x00\x00\x00\xbb\xf3\x08\x00\x02\x00\xd7\x00\x00\x00\x01\xa4\x00\x00\x00\xbf\xf3\x08\x00\x02\x00\xd7\x00\x00\x00\x01\x9d\x00\x00\x00\xc3\xf3\x08\x00\x02\x00\xd7\x00\x00\x00\x01\xa2\x00\x00\x00\xc7\xf3\x08\x00\x02\x00\xdb\x00\x00\x00\x01\x9d\x00\x00\x00\xcb\xf3\x08\x00\x02\x00\xd8\x00\x00\x00\x01\xa3\x00\x00\x00\xcf\xf3\x08\x00\x04\x00\xd7\x00\x00\x00\x01\xa7\x00\x00\x00\x02\xda\x00\x00\x00\x04\x97m\x01\x00'`

Es decir que ha cambiado automáticamente el valor de `\x24` por `$` y el valor de `\x6D` (dentro de los últimos 3 lugares) por `m`.

Hay alguna forma de evitar esta modificación?

Answer (score 0):

Encontré mi error. Estaba confundiendo la manera en como se almacena la información a como me la muestra python en pantalla cuando la imprimo, es decir nunca cambia los datos sino que en pantalla muestra algunos caracteres cambiados. Básicamente estaba buscando convertir esos datos en bytes a enteros, y es tan simple como esto:

```
a = b'\x24\x24\x02\xAF\x00\xA7\ ... \xF3\x08\x00'
lista = list(a)
```